# Do I need to send the original application log files to S3 if I have Cloudwatch running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have my app writing logs to `/var/log/my_app.log`.  I have the logrotator set up daily to rotate the log, so presumably when the log rotate condition is met it will copy over `my_app.log` to `my_app<date>.log`.  I also have the Cloudwatch agent on the same ec2 instance sending files over to Cloudwatch logs.  There they will stay indefinitely I assume (or until a set time set in the aws console). Is it correct to assume that Cloudwatch will always have the first log created and logged regardless of how I rotate the actual log files on the ec2 instance? That is to say, no matter what happens with the rotated logs, I will always have ALL the logs that have been created because they've been sent to cloudwatch?

Answer (score 1):

Any logs that is sent to CloudWatch will not be deleted because of the log rotation. Check out the FAQ section in the following link that has some important questions answered including the log rotation naming schemes and the scenarios in which log events can be truncated or skipped.

(Search for *CloudWatch Logs Agent FAQs* in the following link)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html

Your assumption is correct on the log retention. CloudWatch logs are stored indefinitely by default.

Here is the quote from [Amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html)

> **Log Retention** – By default, logs are kept indefinitely and never expire. You can adjust the retention policy for each log group, keeping the indefinite retention, or choosing a retention period between 10 years and one day.